# How to block Instagram news feed, stories, etc and only use it as a chat app with Instagram API(is this possible)?

Tags: ios, instagram

Basically, I always get really distracted by social media but I have friends on there I want to chat with so I don't want to delete the apps/accounts. There is a newsfeed eradicator extension for facebook which works perfectly, in the same way I was wondering if it's possible to use the Instagram API to block my newsfeed and stories so that I don't see it everytime I open the app? Or is there any other way to do this? Thank you.